# PHP Zip unable to close()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a couple files from wordpress /uploads folder using php and I get this error:
`Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Can't remove file: No such file or directory in /www/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 32` (relative to `$zip->close();` and bellow "if")
I use a plugin to inject PHP on the page.

I basically have a couple dozens checkboxes that when I press "Generate", it gets the name of the file like 07/2019/blabla (with code I get uploads folder + extension, checkbox only hold the media location + name file).

I checked and it's creating the Zip on /uploads, .pdf files exist but it crashes on the close part and when I download and try to extract I get `the archive is either in unknown format or damaged`

Any advise please?

```
if(isset($_POST['files'])) {
    $error = ""; //error holder
    $upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
    if(isset($_POST['createzip'])){
        $post = $_POST; 

        if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0){ 

            // open zip
            $zip_file = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/'.time().".zip";
            $zip_name = time().".zip";

            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            if ($zip->open($zip_file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
                $error .= ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.<br>");
            }

            foreach ($post['files'] as $file) {
                // generate filename to add to zip
                $filepath = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/' . $file . '.pdf';

                if (file_exists($filepath)) {
                  $zip->addFile($filepath) or $error .= ("ERROR: Could not add the file $filename<br>");
                } else {
                  $error .= ("File $filepath doesnt exit.<br>");
                }
            }

            $zip->close();      
            if ($zip->close() !== true ) {
                die($zip->getStatusString()."\n");
            }

            if(file_exists($zip_file)){
                $error .= $zip_file; 
                ob_end_clean();
                // push to download the zip
                header('Content-type: application/zip');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
                header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file));
                readfile($zip_file);
                unlink($zip_file);
            }


        }
    }
}
echo $error;
```

Comment: _“I use a plugin to inject PHP on the page”_ – maybe that is the problem? Seeing that the error message mentions “eval”, my first guess would be, that this somehow messes up the execution context (regarding script working directories, or something like that.) You should really rather try and place this within your code base somewhere, instead of trying to insert it via plugins that eval code in arbitrary places.

Comment: @misorude so maybe place the php part in the header.php of the theme? Or something else?

Comment: Is it possible to close the .zip on a certain location? Because it is opening on the right place but not closing the right place?

Comment: if you are using linux , pls can you try to give permission 775 and www-data to folder

Comment: I found out that I have 2 issues that I don't know. 1) The problem is inside the `if(file_exists($zip_file)){` because when I comment I'm able to download directly on ftp and workds.
2) inside the .zip don't show only the .pdf but all the folders structure matching ftp file location... any advise please?

Comment: *I fixed the 2º issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `$zip->close();` I replaced all code for this:

```
if(file_exists($zip_file)){             
                header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
                header("Content-Type: application/zip");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
                header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zip_file));
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($zip_file)."\"");
                readfile($zip_file);
                unlink($zip_file);
                exit;               
            }
```